# Grouping and sorting with traversal

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 types of nodes : City and Event

City can HOST many events, each event is hosted by only 1 city.

Events can be linked between them with a LINKED relationship (events linked can be .

I want to find for a given city, the events hosted in this city grouped by linked events.

For example :

```
Events happened in C1 : E1, E2, E3, E4
Events happened in C2 : Ew, Ex, Ey, Ez
Events happened in C3 : Ea, Eb, Ec, Ed
```

Links:

```
E1 -> Ew -> Ea -> E2 -> Ex -> Ey
E3 -> Eb -> E4 -> Ez -> Ec -> Ed
```

I'm looking for a way to return:

```
for C1 : [E1,E2], [E3,E4]
or for C2 : [Ew,Ex,Ey], [Ez]
or for C3 : [Eb,Ec,Ed], [Ea]
```

Could this be done by Traversal ?

Answer (score 2):

Setup your sample dataset:

```
MERGE (E1:Event { id: "E1" })
MERGE (E2:Event { id: "E2" })
MERGE (E3:Event { id: "E3" })
MERGE (E4:Event { id: "E4" })
MERGE (Ew:Event { id: "Ew" })
MERGE (Ex:Event { id: "Ex" })
MERGE (Ey:Event { id: "Ey" })
MERGE (Ez:Event { id: "Ez" })
MERGE (Ea:Event { id: "Ea" })
MERGE (Eb:Event { id: "Eb" })
MERGE (Ec:Event { id: "Ec" })
MERGE (Ed:Event { id: "Ed" })
MERGE (C1:Location { city: "C1" })
MERGE (C2:Location { city: "C2" })
MERGE (C3:Location { city: "C3" })
MERGE (C1)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(E1)
MERGE (C1)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(E2)
MERGE (C1)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(E3)
MERGE (C1)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(E4)
MERGE (C2)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ew)
MERGE (C2)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ex)
MERGE (C2)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ey)
MERGE (C2)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ez)
MERGE (C3)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ea)
MERGE (C3)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Eb)
MERGE (C3)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ec)
MERGE (C3)<-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(Ed)
CREATE (E1)-[:LINKED]->(Ew)-[:LINKED]->(Ea)
CREATE (Ea)-[:LINKED]->(E2)-[:LINKED]->(Ex)-[:LINKED]->(Ey)
CREATE (E3)-[:LINKED]->(Eb)-[:LINKED]->(E4)
CREATE (E4)-[:LINKED]->(Ez)-[:LINKED]->(Ec)-[:LINKED]->(Ed)
```

And here is the query to get the results:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(c:Location)
WHERE c.city = "C1"
MATCH p=(a)-[:LINKED*]->(e)-[:LINKED*]->(b)
WHERE NOT (a)<-[:LINKED]-() AND NOT (b)-[:LINKED]->()
WITH nodes(p) AS links, c
RETURN DISTINCT [event IN links WHERE 
     (event)-[:HAPPENED_IN]-(c) | event.id] AS events
```

Results for C1:

```
+-------------+
| events      |
+-------------+
| ["E1","E2"] |
| ["E3","E4"] |
+-------------+
2 rows
34 ms
```

Results for C2:

```
+------------------+
| events           |
+------------------+
| ["Ew","Ex","Ey"] |
| ["Ez"]           |
+------------------+
2 rows
37 ms
```

Results for C3:

```
+------------------+
| events           |
+------------------+
| ["Ea"]           |
| ["Eb","Ec","Ed"] |
+------------------+
2 rows
38 ms
```

Comment: Thank you Kenny for your answer, but I was looking to do it with Traversal API. I've already did something similar to your solution. It works perfect but performance with an important amount of nodes is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add a visual graph model? In general if you want to start with the Java-API just use the basic methods like node.getRelationships() and then go from there.

What you would do,

1. for each city
2. get all events in that city, put them in a set
3. take first event from the set
4. check if there is a connection over multiple hops (e.g. using shortest-path) to the other events in the city, if so, put all connected ones into a group and remove all of those connected events from the original set (they are a cluster anyway and not connected to the other events)
5. when set is empty, output the groups for the city, else continue with 3.